# AWS VPC CNI PLUGIN - Error: container runtime network not ready due to NetworkPluginNotReady - How to Resolve

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eks, aws-eks

I am facing difficulty in this, maybe the answer is simple so if someone knows the answer, please comment here.

I have created an EKS cluster using the following manifest.

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: test-cluster
  region: us-west-2
  version: "1.29"

vpc:
  subnets:
    public:
      us-west-2a: { id: subnet-094d01de2dd2148c0 }
      us-west-2b: { id: subnet-04429e132a1f42826 }
      us-west-2c: { id: subnet-028a738bdafc344c6 }

nodeGroups:
  - name: ng-spot
    instanceType: t3.medium
    labels: { role: builders }
    desiredCapacity: 2
    minSize: 2
    maxSize: 4
    volumeSize: 30
    ssh:
      allow: true
      publicKeyName: techies
    tags:
      Name: ng-spot
    maxPodsPerNode:  110
```

This cluster is for testing purposes, so I am using the `t3.medium` instance with the maximum pod limit `110`.

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k get nodes
NAME                                          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-192-168-37-0.us-west-2.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   26m   v1.29.0-eks-5e0fdde
ip-192-168-86-42.us-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   26m   v1.29.0-eks-5e0fdde
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.allocatable.pods}{"\n"}'
110 110
```

This ensures that I can create `110` pods on each node.

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k create deployment test-deploy --image nginx --replicas 50
deployment.apps/test-deploy created
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k get po
NAME                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
test-deploy-859f95ffcc-2c5k6   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          19s
test-deploy-859f95ffcc-2p9rh   1/1     Running             0          19s
test-deploy-859f95ffcc-468wm   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          18s
.
.
test-deploy-859f95ffcc-xxm7z   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          18s
test-deploy-859f95ffcc-z88x6   1/1     Running             0          19s
```

Here, the remaining pods not getting IP

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k events po test-deploy-859f95ffcc-xxm7z
```

```
1s (x5 over 55s)         Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox    Pod/test-deploy-859f95ffcc-m7t62                   (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "528eaad224c5578435db12a57a8fa7063a03423b28d57c681bab742cc8389a1a": plugin type="aws-cni" name="aws-cni" failed (add): add cmd: failed to assign an IP address to container
```

The following are the subnets and their IP availability

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ aws eks describe-cluster --name test-cluster --query "cluster.resourcesVpcConfig.su
bnetIds"
[
    "subnet-094d01de2dd2148c0",
    "subnet-04429e132a1f42826",
    "subnet-028a738bdafc344c6"
]
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-094d01de2dd2148c0 subnet-04429e132a1f42826 subnet-028a738bdafc344c6 --query 'Subnets[*].[SubnetId,AvailableIpAddressCount]' --output text

subnet-028a738bdafc344c6        8167
subnet-094d01de2dd2148c0        8185
subnet-04429e132a1f42826        8168
```

I have updated the VPC CNI

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ kubectl describe daemonset aws-node --namespace kube-system | grep amazon-k8s-cni: | cut -d : -f 3
v1.16.0-eksbuild.1
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ aws eks create-addon --cluster-name test-cluster --addon-name vpc-cni --addon-version v1.17.1-eksbuild.1 \
-service>     --service-account-role-arn arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/AmazonEKSVPCCNIRole
{
    "addon": {
        "addonName": "vpc-cni",
        "clusterName": "test-cluster",
        "status": "CREATING",
        "addonVersion": "v1.17.1-eksbuild.1",
        "health": {
            "issues": []
        },
        "addonArn": "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:111122223333:addon/test-cluster/vpc-cni/fec7333d-c1fc-c2fc-1287-c14beaa883f8",
        "createdAt": "2024-03-22T19:35:54.685000+05:30",
        "modifiedAt": "2024-03-22T19:35:54.703000+05:30",
        "serviceAccountRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/AmazonEKSVPCCNIRole",
        "tags": {}
    }
}
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ aws eks describe-addon --cluster-name test-cluster --addon-name vpc-cni --query addon.addonVersion --output text
v1.17.1-eksbuild.1
```

After that, I have terminated the existing instances, since that the nodes art not getting ready.

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k get nodes
NAME                                           STATUS     ROLES    AGE     VERSION
ip-192-168-40-177.us-west-2.compute.internal   NotReady   <none>   86s     v1.29.0-eks-5e0fdde
ip-192-168-83-11.us-west-2.compute.internal    NotReady   <none>   3m29s   v1.29.0-eks-5e0fdde
```

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k describe nodes ip-192-168-40-177.us-west-2.compute.internal

Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:45:20 +0530   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:44:49 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:45:20 +0530   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:44:49 +0530   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:45:20 +0530   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:44:49 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:45:20 +0530   Fri, 22 Mar 2024 19:44:49 +0530   KubeletNotReady              container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized
```

I would like to know why this is happening, if someone know the answer please comment.

- First, why the Pods didn't get IP even though the pod limit was set to the maximum
- Second, why the nodes are not ready after updating the VPC CNI plugin